# AngularJS forms for object with subobjects

Tags: angularjs

How come subobjects do not get the two-way binding:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.doc = { "foo": "bar", "baz": { "zab": "rab" }}
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <label><span>Foo</span><input ng-model="doc.foo"></label>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Baz</legend>
      <label ng-repeat="(key,val) in doc.baz">
        <span>{{key}}</span><input ng-model="val">
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <pre><code>{{doc | json}}</code></pre>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I edit the `foo`, I can see it update. But if I edit the `zab`, I cannot see any changes.

Is there some way to make this work, and if not, another data construct (like `baz` being an array of objects) which could be made to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ng-model to this:

```
<span>{{key}}</span><input ng-model="doc.baz[key]">
```

The reason that val isn't updating your outer scope (testCtrl's scope) is that ng-repeat creates a new scope for each iteration - so you are only binding the input box to the local (iteration's) scope copy of val, not the parent's scope part of your larger object.

Comment: Oh, man, that was simple. I thought I had tried that already, but I'm glad it works. Thank you! :)